# How to access audio metadata in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, audio, metadata

Why the return code is false?

How can use audio metadata information by using wp function?

```
require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/media.php' );

$audio_url = 'https://example.com/audio.mp3';
$data = wp_read_audio_metadata( $audio_url );

$filesize = isset( $data['filesize'] ) ? $data['filesize'] : '';
$mime_type = isset( $data['mime_type'] ) ? $data['mime_type'] : '';
$fileformat = isset( $data['fileformat'] ) ? $data['fileformat'] : '';
$playtime_seconds = isset( $data['playtime_seconds'] ) ? $data['playtime_seconds'] : '';
$playtime_string = isset( $data['playtime_string'] ) ? $data['playtime_string'] : '';
$created_timestamp = isset( $data['created_timestamp'] ) ? $data['created_timestamp'] : '';

echo $playtime_seconds;
```

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/43957617/6773883

Comment: And this https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/254148/is-wp-read-audio-metadata-function-deprecated

Comment: Thank You, @omukiguy